# SQLCE Connections: Keep them open or let them close?

Tags: mobile, sql-server-ce

Keeping performance on a mobile device in mind, what do you think is the best approach with an SQLCE Connection. Keep it open for the duration of the application or let it close whenever a call to the database is needed.

Obviously this depends a little on the nature of your application however I'm curious to hear what the group has implemented and why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should definitely watch Steve Lasker's [PDC08 session about SQL Server Compact Edition](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC40/). There's a part about performance, best practices and his own benchmarks (~37:00).

In short, keep it open, try to reuse commands, and use SqlCeResultSet for bulk operations.

Comment: Also grabbed sample code for Lasker's Blog at: http://blogs.msdn.com/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/31/pdc-2008-embedding-sql-server-compact-in-desktop-and-device-applications.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For my device, I kept it open during the lifetime of the application.  If the functionality of the application depends on the SQLCE connection throughout, this makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

Get Late, Release Early. Open the Connection as late as possible in the operation, and close it as soon as is possible. Open SQL connections are not good.

Comment: That is true for a server database but not at all for an embedded database like SQL CE, which works in process with normally a single concurrent user.

Comment: After working with access, I tend to use this model regardless of the product nature. =)

Comment: With Compact Edition, there's a relatively large overhead to opening a connection and you are "encouraged" by this fact to keep your connections around if you plan to reuse them.

Comment: I voted this answer down as the advice does not apply to SQL Server Compact edition.