# SQL Query gets slower with each iteration?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, sql-server-ce

Is there anyway to make this SQL query faster? It searches a `.sdf` database for matching words. The data is arranged in alphabetical order. Currently it takes about 10-15 seconds to search, the first iteration of the search seems to be rather quick however the search becomes slower with each iteration? Why is this? Sorry this is my first experience with SQL.

```
private void Search_Database() //Searches SQL Database for matching words
{
    Possible_Words.Clear();
    using (var cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Resource\Wordlist.sdf"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            string[] Final_Search_Array = (string[])Packaged_Search_Array.ToArray(typeof(string)); // Receives  and Unwraps Packaged Array
            int Search_Array_Index = Final_Search_Array.Length - 1;
            for (; Search_Array_Index != -1; Search_Array_Index = Search_Array_Index - 1)
            {
                switch (Final_Search_Array[Search_Array_Index].Length)
                {
                    case 2:
                        Search_Table = "[2 Letter Words]";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Search_Table = "[3 Letter Words]";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Search_Table = "[4 Letter Words]";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Search_Table = "[5 Letter Words]";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Search_Table = "[6 Letter Words]";
                        break;
                }
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from " + Search_Table + " where [Melted] like '%" + Final_Search_Array[Search_Array_Index] + "%'";
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Possible_Words.Add(reader["Word"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
    FullList_PossibleWords.Add(Possible_Words);
}
```

Comment: SqlParameter why waste precious CPU cycles trying to secure my code.

Comment: Jesus has a point (obtuse though it may be).  Use `SqlParameter`s to build your command statement.  Also, if you're re-opening your `SqlConnection` each time you iterate through a loop, you should put your `using SqlCeConnection` statement outside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tips:

1. Instead of using `*` in your query use all field names.
2. Create an index on *`Melted`* field.
3. Build your query outside of creating Connection object and Command
4. Open connection when you need it not in beginning of your code

If you consider this tips your code become faster.

Comment: Actually, with single user, in memory databases (SQL Compact at least) the general rules of connection handling do nor apply. There is a lot of overhead involved in creating them and they should be reused if possible.

Comment: This SO questions covers this point.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386223/sqlce-connections-keep-them-open-or-let-them-close